# function not getting returned at a proper return statement for some test cases

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

This is my code.

Issue :
 I am getting an incorrect output for the test case : a=100 b=54 .

Problem Found :
Why is it that when the first `if` condition in the method `computeGcd` is invoked (i.e when `a==b` or `a` is divisible by `b`) that it is not returning from this if block back to the line in the main method from where it was called?

Instead it is going to the last return statement in the method and it is returning the old value of 'b' from there. What am I missing?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    if (a >= b) {
        System.out.println("\n\nfinal values are: " + computeGcd(a, b) 
                + " for a is=" + a + " and b=" + b);}
    else
        System.out.println(computeGcd(b, a));
    sc.close();
}

public static int computeGcd(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("out side a is=" + a + " and b=" + b);
    if (a == b || a % b == 0) {
        System.out.println("Inside final : a is=" + a + " and b=" + b);
        return b;
    } else {
        a = (a - b * (a / b));
        if (a > b) {
            System.out.println("Inside test a>b : a is=" + a + " and b=" + b);
            computeGcd(a, b);
        }
        if (b > a) {
            System.out.println("Inside test a<b : a is=" + a + " and b=" + b);
            computeGcd(b, a);
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("exiting else");
    System.out.println("i m here :P ");
    return b;
}
```

Debug for Test Case :100 54

Comment: Are you asking us to debug or you already debugged?

Comment: i have already done that.I just left all those sysouts just in case someone tries out the code, then it will be easier for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive calls don't `return`.

```
if (a > b) {
    System.out.println("Inside test a>b : a is=" + a + " and b=" + b);
    return computeGcd(a, b); // <-- add return
} else { // if (b > a) {
    System.out.println("Inside test a<b : a is=" + a + " and b=" + b);
    return computeGcd(b, a); // <-- add return
}
```

**Alternatively**

The greatest possible gcd is the square root of the minimum of the two terms. You can start with that value and iterate backwards. Something like,

```
public static int computeGcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    }
    for (int i = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.min(a, b)); i >= 2; i--) {
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

which returns `2` (for `100, 54`) because one half of `54` is `27` which is 3<sup>3</sup> leaving the only common denominators being 2 and 1.

Comment: Thanks , it is working. But i just wanted to ask two things 
1. why should i use return statements in recursive calls. I am only required to call the function again so i can just write the function names with the inputs.
2.Why is the value of b printing the old value in my code . 

But thanks for your reply. My cide is working properly but still i have these doubts if u can help :)

Comment: I would like to clarify my code please :) I am actually missing on some concept related to recursive calls if u can help me with that .

Comment: When you recurse, you invoke the method again (with a new call stack); that is why you must capture (or return) the result (it's a new invocation, with new local variables).

Comment: Also in your code, if you run it for test case : a=4 , b=4 , GCD(4,4) from your code is 2 . can u check that ? 

A possible edit from my side that can fix your code. 


public static int computeGcd(int a, int b) {
  if(a!=b)
  {
  int max=0;
     for (int i = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.min(a, b)); i >= 2; i--) {
         if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
          if(max<i)   
           max=i;
          if(i>=a)
           break;
         }
     }
     return max;
  }
  else if(a==b)
     return (a>b?b:a);
  
  else 
   return 1;
 }

Comment: waoo.. i was missing on this concept :) cheers ! and thanks :)

Comment: Sorry this is the edit :


A possible edit from my side that can fix your code. 

'public static int computeGcd(int a, int b) {
  if(a!=b && (a!=1 || b!=1))
  {
  int max=1;
     for (int i = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.min(a, b)); i >= 2; i--) {
         if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
          if(max<i)   
           max=i;
          if(i>=a)
           break;
         }
     }
     return max;
  }
  else if(a==b)
     return (a>b?b:a);
  
  else 
   return 1;
 }'